# Mail is not sent from website's PHP Contact form

Tags: php

i m using a php form for sending the contact email from my website. the code is ok and working fine on one website but not working in second website. both website having difference server space and hosting. Not showing any error on page

code is below :

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST['rohini_name'] ;
$contact = $_REQUEST['rohini_contact'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['rohini_email'] ;
$remark = $_REQUEST['rohini_message'] ; 

$MailTxt = "Following are Details" . "\r\n" .
"============================" . "\r\n" .
"Name : " . $name . "\r\n" .
"Mobile : " . $contact . "\r\n" .
"Email : " . $email . "\r\n" .
```

"Remark : " . $remark . "\r\n";

```
$to = "ballu9868@gmail.com";
$subject = "Enquiry from rohiniseeds.com";
$headers = "From: www.rohiniseeds.com";

mail($to,$subject,$MailTxt,$headers);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ask your hosting to make sure that [mail](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) funstion is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an **IF** statement around the **mail($to,$subject,$MailTxt,$headers)** function as follows:

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$MailTxt,$headers)){
 echo 'Success!';
} else {
 echo 'Error!';
}
```

If it says *Success* then you know that it's being sent by the server, and the problem is when it's trying to hit the inbox. If it says error, then the problem related to the server.

Also, please use **email@rohiniseeds.com** in the from header, which is a valid email address, instead of the URL of the website.

Comment: thank you very much sir, it is a very helpful reply ! thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: thx for replying sir ! but the code is running fine on other hosting and sending mail successfully. it seems that the problem is with my current hosting plan.